# Specifying initial conditions for matlab function in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a matlab file that I want to run from within Python. I have matlab.engine and I know how to start and run the code. However, the matlab file needs inputs for initial conditions. So far, I've just been manually entering them in matlab but I want to do that in python. Is there a way I can do that?

My current code is this:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.main(nargout=0)
```

I need to find a way to add stuff here that would allow me to change the initial conditions. The matlab code is as follows:

```
function [] = main(input1, input2 ..)
input1 = 
input2 =
```

..

I want to edit the inputs in python, instead of having to open matlab every time.

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: Yes added above

Comment: Your MATLAB code should be a function, not a script. Then you can call the function with its arguments. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pass-data-to-matlab-from-python.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo omg thank you, all I had to do was convert my input to float and it worked!